# Database Modeling issue

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, erd

I'm trying to develop a database with the following:
category,Item, form.

Each Item belongs to a category and each item can have different forms based on its category, where these forms have different attributes.

e.g

1) Category A, belongs to Item1,
   item1 uses form A

2) Category B belongs to Item2,
   item2 uses form B.

I am no sure my representation is accurate.

[image]

Comment: *"each item can have different forms based on its category"* This seems to imply there's either a 1:N or a M:N relationship between forms and categories, but you didn't model that.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' im not sure how to do that

Comment: Forms are related to categories then, isn't it? So you must create a pivot table for category-form and the items will be related with a concrete form and that relation can be followed to a category, you don't need both.